# Mysql create a single table name for the same schema type multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I was creating 10 tables with same schema for loading application LOG.

I was creating 10 tables with same schema and at the end I do create a alias name which will represent all those 10 tables.

So it take care about current active table selection to insert the records, so once table1 gets filled more records it will choose table2 and next table3....

So while selecting a record, it will check all the 10 tables for the requested record.....

Now my question is, I forgot about how did I created and which statement I have used.

If anyone knows then please let me know about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reinventing [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html), please use the tools MySQL provides for this, it will save you a lot of time & headaches.